# error BC30657 on TeamCity - 'Delegate Sub SubName(x as Type1)' has a return type that is not supported or parameter types that are not supported

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, teamcity

When building my solution in TeamCity I got this error :

E:\BuildServer\Agents\BuildAgent1\BuildAgent\work\f1dbe38e175d8263\er.vb(89, 43): error BC30657: 'Delegate Sub SubName(x as Type1)' has a return type that is not supported or parameter types that are not supported.

Although it is building in Visual Studio on the development machine. any idea why I get this error ?

Comment: Is your TeamCity using Msbuild version 12? Because that's the version VS2013 uses.

Comment: Yes it does use msbuild 12.